# How to only update the dropdown list of chosen-select

Tags: jquery-chosen

I know that `chosen` consists of an input search `class="default"` and ul dropdownlist `class="chosen-drop"`.

`chosen:updated` updates the whole chosen-select (input search and dropdownlist)

So the question is: what if I want to update only the ul dropdownlist without updating the input search? (`chosen:updated` is deleting my input search text while updating)

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is selector for input element in chosen dropdown. I have keyup event on it and this is my code inside:

```
$('.chosen-container').on('keyup','input', function(){

   var $text = $(this).val(); 
   var $select = $('select');    

   function write_text(input) {
     input.val($text);
   }

   function ajax_load(input) {
     $.ajax({
       url : Routing.generate('just.some.route'),
       type: 'POST',
       data: {text : $text},
       success: function (html) {
            $select.html(html);
            $select.trigger("chosen:updated");
            write_text(input);
       }
     });
   }

   ajax_load($(this));
});
```

You can also define this functions globally outside event and use it in other ajax calls from chosen.